# LIBC SigaBRT crash 0x000000000000311e

Tags: java, crash, libc

We had a weird crash in our app. It looks like an error with C libc.so happened. The stacktrace is the following:

```
Crashed: Thread: SIGABRT  0x000000000000311e
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
   at (Ausente)()
```

We searched but nothing that help was found. Does anyone have any idea about this error?